# Is it possible to use CListCtrl without MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, win32gui

I would like to use CListCtrl in my Win32 project. I have tried to add MFC to my project but I have failed. I only need CListCtrl. Can I somehow add only CListCtrl without whole MFC.

Comment: It is a wrapper around the ListView control. You can use that just fine without MFC. Add one to your dialog in the resource editor, or call CreateWindow.

Comment: With ListView I have problem how to insert multiple columns. Now to add something to ListView I use  SendMessage(listBox, , ,);

Comment: @NikolaGaić have you seen link in my answer? You have ListView_InsertColumn, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298344(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`CListCtrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfshke78.aspx) class is just a wrapper around a standard Win32 [ListView control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx), which you can use without MFC. The MFC sources are available in this source path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\atlmfc
```

For coding a ListView without MFC, see the [ListView documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx).

Or you might consider using another library, such as [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Tnx, this is info I needed. I tought they are diferent controls.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use appropriate function or method to change list-control's behavior so that multiple columns are shown. Use [CListCtrl::SetView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0t92ste.aspx) with `LV_VIEW_DETAILS`.

You may also use [LVM_SETVIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb761220)  with the same value.

If you are using dialog editor of Visual Studio (MFC or Win32), you simply need to change **View** property.